# Laravel storing model with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to store a model, which is a link table.
The table:

```
Schema::create('game_has_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('game_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Game_Has_Users model:

```
     class Game_Has_Users extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'game_has_users';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function game()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Game', 'game_id');
    }
}
```

I want to store a Game and after that, the Game_Has_Users model should be created using a user id and game id.

```
try {
      $game = Game::create([]);
      $user = User::where('name', $request->input('name'))->first();

//      $game_users = Game_Has_Users::create([]);
//      $game_users->user = $user->id;
//      $game_users->game = $game->id;
//      $game_users->save();

      $test = Game_Has_Users::create([
          'user_id' => $user->id,
          'game_id' => $game->id
      ]);
      return response()->json(['t' => $test, 'status' => 'ok']);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
      return response()->json(['status' => 'failed', 'message' => $e]);
    }
```

However, I always get the following response: status: failed, message: [].
It does not have an exception so I have no idea what I did wrong.
I tried different approaches such as: having default values for game id and user id, different methods to save the link model. $game->id and $user->id do have a values when I send them through a response.

Comment: `Game_Has_Users` should not be a model. It's a pivot table. you have a many to many relationship between game and users so define that in your game and users models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `$fillable` property;

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'game_id'];
```

in your `Game_Has_Users` model

Answer (score 3):

**Conform to Eloquent**

Eloquent expects every table to have a single primary key, so make sure you add an id column to this table.  Without this column, you'll have problems when taking advantage of various eloquent methods.

Inside your migration, this will add an autoincrementing primary key:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

**Utilize Relationships**

Next, if I'm correct, Games_Has_Users looks like a many to many relationship.

Therefore, you don't need to have a model for this table.  Using the appropriate belongsToMany relationships, you can attach models to each other:

```
$game = Game::find(1);
$user = User::find(1);
// Assuming the User model has a games() belongsToMany relationship;
$user->games()->attach($game);
// or the inverse
$games->users()->attach($user);
```

Then you can access the collection of games attached to a user with `$user->games`.

Read through https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many